# Screen press (on mobile) not registering on intended element Unity 3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a grid of buttons (using grid layout group). I created this by adding a UI element and duplicating it 9 times (10 buttons) and then just applying a grid layout group to the parent object while all of the buttons were still at 0,0,0. This laid out the buttons exactly as i wanted in the grid shape that i chose. When i run this on PC and click a button, it registers perfectly. When i build it down to an apk and put it on my android, the buttons don't click when you press on them, but rather when you press way off to the right in some empty field space. But the "clickable grid area" as i'll call it, is perfectly transposed into that open field space. So i have my 5x2 visible button elements on the screen. If i touch them, nothing happens. Randomly touch in empty space until one of the buttons activates, and the clickable grid is in the exact shape of the visible elements except not on top of the elements. I'm not 100% familiar with resolution settings yet but i don't think that has all too much to do with this. What am i missing and what settings can i change?

Answer (score 0):

so the problem ended up being that the anchors were not set to center, they were set to top left. This was set automatically by the grid layout group component. Remove grid layout, set positions manually, all is well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define column and row for each button

Comment: how do i define that?

Comment: In XML 
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"